# Howto simulate latency in meteor collection insert/update/remove

Tags: meteor

When I call Meteor.methods I use

```
var wait = function(sim){
  if (!sim) {
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var future = new Future();
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      future['return']();
    }, latency * 1000);
    future.wait();
  }
};
```

to simulate latency on the server. Is there a way to simulate latency when dealing directly with Meteor.collections?

**update**:

I want to call

```
mycollection.insert({whatever:iwant}, function(error, result){   
   ... show that the server collection is updated now ...
});
... show that the server collection is not updated yet ...
```

To test this behavior i want to simulate latency on the **serverside** like I do it for Meteor.method calls already.

Comment: Latency is automatically simulated on the client with Collection methods like insert/update/remove, but what would it mean to simulate latency *on the server*?

Comment: It's automatically *compensated* for on the client. That's the thing with Meteor - even if you simulate latency for DDP, you won't really notice anything, unless you define different allow/deny rules on the client and server. The client powers collections through minimongo, so  the client is never waiting on the server's response to perform an action - it just uses the server's response to patch up the minimongo DB if they disagree.

Comment: sorry, i think i does not explain what i want to do, correctly. updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate latency using client side methods too

Client side call

```
Meteor.call("something");
```

Client side 'virtual method'

```
Meteor.methods({
    something:function() {
        Collection.insert({this_is_virtual: true});
    }
});
```

Server side method

```
Meteor.methods({
    something: function() {
        wait();
        Collection.insert({this_is_virtual: false});
    });
});
```

The client side method will create fake data for the sake of latency compensation with the value `this_is_virtual` as `true`. As soon as the real data arrives it will change to false.

You can use this to create simulated data on the client. The same methods can also be used on the server side. You can use `this.isSimulation` to determine if it is a latency compensation, 'virtual', method.

Client side collections are added using this 'latency compensation'. So that **even if you have simulated latency it wouldn't do anything**.

This is one of the founding principles of meteor. If you want to avoid it you would have to use a method/call like the one above, but without a client side simulation stub. But I suspect this would not be worth it because the latency compensation is a helpful feature.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i know how methods work and that collections are Meteor.methods too internally. I hope my update helps to make clearer what i'm trying to do.

Comment: How does `_id`s get synced between client and server? If I call `Collection.insert` in simulation, how does it happen that `Collection.insert` generates the same `_id` on the server as well?

Comment: @Mitar the _id is generated on the client, and it waits for it to be confirmed by the server. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js#L635

Comment: But this happens only when you call `Collection.insert` directly, not from inside the method. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/881